# Tooltips no funciona bien en Firefox

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, tooltip

Tengo problemas con tooltips en firefox. Cuando lo corro en chrome funciona sin problemas pero al correrlo en firefox no funciona a menos que lo saque del input
Estiy trabajando en Laravel con boostrap

Asi se ve en Chrome

[image: Vista en google chrome]

Y asi en firefox

[image: Vista en firefox]
En firefox funciona solo cuando lo saco de input
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este en mi codigo del tooltip, funciona en ambos pero si el tooltip se encuentra dentro input no funciona en firefox como se ve en la imagen

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input style="z-index:1;" name="abreviatura" type="text" class="form-control @error('abreviatura') is-invalid @enderror" id="abreviatura" value="{{ old('abreviatura') }}" placeholder="Abreviatura del pais" tabindex="0" required>
        <a target="_blank"href="https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/listado-de-paises-con-abreviaturas/" style="float: right; margin-top:-35px; margin-right:10px; z-index:2;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Para más referencia da click">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i></a>
            @error('abreviatura')
                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                 <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                  </span>
              @enderror
               <label for="abreviatura">Abreviatura del pais</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: ¿porque tienes dos href en el **<a>**?  ¿Y ese código que has pegado en la pregunta es el que funciona o el que no funciona?  ¿Y eso lo estas haciendo en que? ¿laravel? ¿codeigniter? ¿asp? ¿php?  Procura concretar mejor la pregunta y pon correctamente sus etiquetas para obtener mejores ayudas, gracias.

Comment: @masterguru Ya le borre eso pero aun asi no funciona, estoy trabajando con laravel y cuando visualizo en chrome si funciona pero para firefox funciona solo cuando el tooltip esta fuera del input

Comment: Sigo preguntándome como pones eso dentro del input, pues el código que has puesto lo muestra fuera:  https://jsfiddle.net/fmtu7xhw/

Comment: @masterguru es verdad, es que pegue lo del codigo del que se ve fuera. ya lo corregi

Comment: Acabo de agregar una respuesta, míratela, adáptala a tu código y si te funciona acepta mi respuesta para que la comunidad lo sepa. En caso contrario dime que problema te surge.

Answer (score 1):

Mi propuesta pasa por no usar z-index ni estilos personalizados sino elementos y clases de bootstrap que nos facilitarán arreglar este comportamiento anómalo.

Propongo usar [input-group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/input-group/) combinado con las clases **input-group-append**, **bg-white** y **border-right-0**,  de este modo para que se parezca lo mejor posible a lo que el OP pretende:

```
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <input name="abreviatura" type="text" class="form-control border-right-0" id="abreviatura" value="abreviatura" placeholder="Abreviatura del pais" tabindex="0" required>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
          <a target="_blank" href="https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/listado-de-paises-con-abreviaturas/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Para más referencia da click">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Aquí dejo un snippet funcional de ejemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  })

</script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <input name="abreviatura" type="text" class="form-control border-right-0" id="abreviatura" value="abreviatura" placeholder="Abreviatura del pais" tabindex="0" required>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
          <a target="_blank" href="https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/listado-de-paises-con-abreviaturas/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Para más referencia da click">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label for="abreviatura">Abreviatura del pais</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ya nos comentas si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Si esta funcionando, ahora solo falta ver como hacer que funcione la etiqueta flotante que tenia, se ve como doble etiqueta y no se minimiza

Comment: No se a que te refieres... en mi respuesta no se ve ninguna doble etiqueta creo... ¿o tu código no era el de la pregunta y habia alguna cosa más que desconozco?